# Set VNC password

Tags: linux, password, vnc

I need some help here.
Is there a way to set the VNC password without a user interaction?
When I run vncpasswd it prompts for a password and then verification of it.
I would like to change the password from script.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have vncserver, so reading the man page over the web and no way to test....

Have you tried writing the password twice to a temp file and using that
as stdin to vncpasswd?

```
echo $password >/tmp/file
echo $password >>/tmp/file  # note >> for append
vncpasswd </tmp/file >/tmp/vncpasswd.1 2>/tmp/vncpasswd.2
```

That's for the bash shell.  But the basic idea should be obvious.
Prompting will wind up in the .1 file and errors in the .2 file

Comment: Ran into the same problem, and this solution helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want a one-liner, this from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30606811/109707

`vncpasswd -f <<< $PASSWORD > "$HOME/.vnc/passwd"`

Or if using x11vnc

`x11vnc -storepasswd $PASSWORD "$HOME/.vnc/passwd"`